# Control for viewing more images in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

When the user clicks a button in my C# app I want to show him bunch of images so that he can pick one. I don't want to do it with file browser,  I want him to be able to view little thumbnails of the images so that he sees what he is picking.

Is there any control I can use to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a Windows Forms control or a WPF control? You should use **tags** to clarify what we are talking about here

Comment: I know Windows Forms only, don't have experience with WPF.

Comment: take a look at here loading multiple imgaes in picturebox control http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/76732-loading-multiple-images-to-a-picture-box/

Answer (score 3):

If you are refering to a WinForms control, I would recommend the free [ImageListView control](http://code.google.com/p/imagelistview/).

Works very well in my own real-world projects. Plus, the author is very responsive and the control seems to have a very high overall code and design quality.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create custom code. Or you can use a WYSIWYG Editor.

Here are 2 popular ones for .NET.

http://www.tinymce.com/

http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: @user1007632 That's why it's important to tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple PictureBox-es in a grid formation in the form that you are creating.

Display one thumbnail in each PictureBox.

I am usually against PictureBox control usage, but in this case, you can't miss.